# Why do I get errors when I #include curl.h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcurl

I'm trying to get libcurl to work with my C++ project.
I've added libcurl to my project.
I've also added the header files, preprocessor and linker configuration.

When adding #include  to my project I get a lot of winnt.h errors:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(1084): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(1084): error C2059: syntax error : '('
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(1084): error C2090: function returns array
>   ...

What is the reason to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't cut (truncate) the error messages. They help us help you.

Comment: +1 on the full error message. And which version of libcurl are you using?

Comment: I'm using libcurl version 7.21.6 (latest)

Comment: Problem solved: you need to include <curl/curl.h> before the Juce includes